# How to add 3rd level category to scrolling dropdown list

Tags: magento-1.9, php, css, phtml

I have long drop down list of subcategory which also includes third level subcategory. i have added using css tricks
reference: https://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/
now im unable to display third level category... it has to display side of subcategory. provide me proper guidelines

[image]

Answer (score 2):

for third level

```
        <script>
var maxHeight = 300;
var maxwidth
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function(){

jQuery("li.level0").hover(function() {

var jQuerycontainer = jQuery(this),
jQuerylist = jQuerycontainer.find("ul.level0"),
jQueryanchor = jQuerycontainer.find("a"),
height = jQuerylist.height() * 1.1, // make sure there is enough room at the bottom
multiplier = height / maxHeight; // needs to move faster if list is taller

// need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout
jQuerycontainer.data("origHeight", jQuerycontainer.height());

// so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
jQueryanchor.addClass("hover");

// make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item
jQuerylist
.show()
.css({

paddingTop: jQuerycontainer.data("origHeight"),
position:'absolute',
});

// don't do any animation if list shorter than max
if (multiplier > 1) {
jQuerycontainer
.css({
height: maxHeight,
overflow: "hidden",



})
.mousemove(function(e) {
var offset = jQuerycontainer.offset();
var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) - (jQuerycontainer.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
if (relativeY > jQuerycontainer.data("origHeight")) {
jQuerylist.css("top", -relativeY +jQuerycontainer.data("origHeight"));
};
});
}

}, function() {

var jQueryel = jQuery(this);

// put things back to normal
jQueryel
.height(jQuery(this).data("origHeight"))
.find("ul")
.css({ })
.hide()
.end()
.find("a")
.removeClass("hover");

})});
jQuery (function() {
jQuery("li.level1").hover(function() {

var jQuerycontainer = jQuery(this),
jQuerylist = jQuerycontainer.find("ul.level1"),
jQueryanchor = jQuerycontainer.find("a"),
height = jQuerylist.height() * 1.1, // make sure there is enough room at the bottom

multiplier = height / maxHeight; // needs to move faster if list is taller

// need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout
jQuerycontainer.data("origHeight", jQuerycontainer.height());

// so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
jQueryanchor.addClass("hover");

// make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item
jQuerylist
.show()
.css({

//paddingTop: jQuerycontainer.data("origHeight"),
position:'relative',
clear:'both',
});

// don't do any animation if list shorter than max


}, function() {
var jQueryel = jQuery(this);

// put things back to normal
// jQueryel
// .height(jQuery(this).data("origHeight"))
// .find("ul")
// .css({ })
// .hide()
// .end()
// .find("a")
// .removeClass("hover");

})});

//Add down arrow only to menu items with submenus
// jQuery(".nav-primary > li:has('ul')").each(function() {
// jQuery(this).find("a:first").append("<img src='images/down-arrow.png' />");
// });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
ol.dropdown {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
}
ol.dropdown li {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ccc;
float: left;
font-weight: bold;
position: relative;
width: 180px;
}
ol.dropdown a:hover {
color: #000;
}
ol.dropdown li a {
color: #222;
display: block;
padding: 20px 8px;
position: relative;
z-index: 904;
}
ol.dropdown li a:hover, ol.dropdown li a.hover {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f3d673;
position: relative;
}
ol.dropdown ul {

display: none;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100px;
z-index: 902;
}
ol.dropdown ul li {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f6f6f6;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
color: #000;
font-weight: normal;
}
ol.dropdown ul li a {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eee !important;
display: block;
}
ol.dropdown ul li a:hover {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f3d673 !important;
display: block;
}
ol.dropdown ul li ul {

display: none;
left: 10px;
background-color: #ffc;
/*right: 0;*/



width: 160px;
z-index: 903;
}
ol.dropdown ul li ul li {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f6f6f6;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc;
color: #000;
font-weight: normal;
}
ol.dropdown ul li ul li a {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eee !important;
display: block;
}
ol.dropdown ul li ul li a:hover {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f3d673 !important;
display: block;
}

</style>
```

[image]

Comment: have you add the css and js function

Comment: as above u sent its added in footer.phtml,, anywhere extra we need to add

Comment: no it working on my side..

Comment: no just added the third level categories and put css and function for that it is working check what are you missing try to alert in second js function it is working or check your html hierarchy

Comment: no changes is reflecting.. i tried all possibilty

Comment: html hierarchy is proper coz it was working before adding the script

Comment: have you test the js or check the any error in js

Comment: no changes after updating z-index

Comment: this jquery only support two level category not third if you achieved to display the third the scroll will not work as your requirement

Comment: i don want third level scroll.. just want it to display as another column

Comment: you have to show third level in that box i am updating the answer it is showing inside the container.

Comment: can you share the demo link of above screenshot

Comment: i don't have a demo of that

Comment: are you trying on localhost??

Comment: yes i am doing on localhost

Comment: please can u update the script.. last time u had said u'll update,, please help me to get proper dropdown

Comment: the last update the answer is showning the third level dropdown in side the container do some css trick an make him prominent so it will it is third level

Comment: but u were getting third level category oustside container last time

Comment: i check later the jquery was not working on that. it is not good way remove my accepted answer..

Comment: oh,, if u get that in proper way please update the answer

Comment: i update the last work i did on that see the update..

Comment: is the above your updated answer????

Comment: yes it is updated answer